# How to downgrade the version of internal nuget package

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure-functions

I am working on a Azure function project, where the version of the nuget packages requires to be within 3.1 (The reason why Azure function nuget package should be within 5.0 version is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63972495/azure-function-v3-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-extensions-dependenc))

So I want to downgrade few versions of internal nuget package.

[image]

I want to downgrade the highlighted version to 3.1. Is there a way to do so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in visual studio check tools-> nuget package manager -> manage nuget package for solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to remove the version you highlighted and download the version that you want to use from Nuget Packet Manager.

[image: NuGet Packet Manager]